# SSH - dpkg: command not found?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, package-management, dpkg

I'm running Ubuntu and trying to install Ajax Push Engine:

This is everything I do since opening the terminal to getting the error:

```
lisandrov@lisandrov-Satellite-L655:~/Desktop$ ssh lisv22@chusmix.com
Password: 
Last login: Fri Sep  9 22:03:07 2011 from 190.220.54.6
-bash-3.2$ ls
ape.deb  backup  data  html  scc  tmp
-bash-3.2$ sudo dpkg -i ape.deb
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong, but I just started learning to use the terminal 10 minutes ago so I have no idea why I'm getting this error. Also dpkg works perfectly outside SSH.

What could be the cause for this error?

Comment: Are you running Debian/Ubuntu?

Comment: yes i'm running Ubuntu

Comment: Check if `/usr/bin/dpkg` exists and if your `PATH` variable is set properly. Unless you've seriously mucked around with your system, I don't think you're running a Debian based distro.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu. At least I know I'm not doing anything wrong, I'll try from Debian tomorrow. `/user/bin/dpkg` exists and it gives me the info about the command. I don't know how to check my `PATH` variable. I can use DPKG on my PC just can't run it on my server for some reason. The server is running Linux also

Comment: wait I echoed $path and it gave me:
`/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` is that ok or not? How do I fix it?

Comment: Log in as root and install `sudo` first. It seems as if it's missing.

Comment: ... or figure out *where* `sudo` is installed and add it to your path.

Comment: But `sudo` does work if I'm not connected to my server. Does that make sense? Once connected to the server, no commands work. (And they used to work)

Comment: Also they used to work. I uploaded and moved `ape.deb` with the terminal. After moving it suddenly all commands stopped working.

Comment: @lisandro, you are aware that the computer that you ssh from and the chusmix server are separate machines, right? And that the setup on one might very well be different from the other. The chusmix server might, for example (if it's not your server), not have `sudo` installed and might even not be a Ubuntu machine as far as I know. I suggest that you read up on how to use a Unix system from the command line, for example from the Ubuntu documentation [UsingTheTerminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) and [AptGetHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that your shell cannot find `sudo`.

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

Almost certainly, `sudo` needs to be installed. Login as root and run:

```
# apt-get install sudo
```